# Calculate sum of line lengths in R

Tags: r, polygon, line, sf, summarizing

I have `object1` with polygons and `object2` with lines. I am looking for a way in R (preferably with the package sf) to calculate the sum of line lengths from `object2` for each polygon in `object1`.

The resulting object should have the same features as `object1`, but with as additional attribute the length of the lines from `object2` across each polygon of `object1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read some data:

```
> polys = st_read("./lines_poly.shp", quiet=TRUE)
> lines = st_read("./lines_line.shp", quiet=TRUE)
> plot(polys$geom)
> plot(lines$geom,lwd=2,add=TRUE)
```

Gives:

[image]

Key operation is intersection:

```
> ints = st_intersection(lines, polys)
```

Which returns this:

```
> ints
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -3.435776 ymin: 54.40466 xmax: -2.731861 ymax: 54.59513
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
    ID ID.1                       geometry
1    0    0 MULTILINESTRING ((-3.213695...
5    4    0 MULTILINESTRING ((-3.296152...
2    1    1 MULTILINESTRING ((-2.792331...
4    3    1 LINESTRING (-2.733722 54.50...
5.1  4    1 LINESTRING (-2.940045 54.53...
```

which is all the intersections of the lines with the polygons and ID attributes from the source lines and polygons. Map:

```
> plot(polys$geom)
> plot(ints$geom,lwd=2,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

So to get the length in each polygon, sum up the line segment lengths by polygon ID, which is ID.0:

```
> tapply(st_length(ints), ints$ID.1,sum)
       0        1 
61739.89 33265.18
```

Polygons that don't have any lines in them are missing from this list, so you can't simply put them in the vector. Also, they might be in a random order...

To put these values in the right place in the polygon object a bit of `match` and indexing:

```
> polys$ltot = rep(0,nrow(polys))
> polys$ltot[match(names(ltot),polys$ID)] = ltot


> polys
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -3.447643 ymin: 54.30678 xmax: -2.729412 ymax: 54.61172
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
  ID                       geometry     ltot
1  0 POLYGON ((-3.428417 54.4994... 61739.89
2  1 POLYGON ((-2.940898 54.4747... 33265.18
3  2 POLYGON ((-3.238902 54.3676...     0.00
```

Then you can do:

```
> plot(polys[,"ltot"])
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea for SpatialLinesDataFrame objetcs?

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 convert to `sf` using `sf::st_as_sf` then proceed as above...

Comment: Thanks, yes. I used the st_as_sf( ) function!